# Enable saving only when specific columns were changed in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I would like to force the user of a QGIS project file to edit 4 columns in the attribute table and only when those columns were edited the saving of the changes is enabled. Is this possible in QGIS 2.18?

Comment: Can you describe the workflow more precisely? Are there some specific layers in the QGIS project file? How are you specifying the columns? Do you mean they can't save the project file or they cant save the layer? Can they save the layer with 2 changed columns but not the project, not that that makes any difference because the project merely points to the layer...

Comment: The project file includes postgres views on postgis tables which are seperated in layers. In all layers are columns which are not editable (this is set in the frontend as well as in the backend), except the 4 mentioned columns. When I say "save" I mean saving edits in the views (aka attribute tables). Right now users could edit one column of those 4 and save the edits to write it to the DB tables (via the views). But I want that this "sending of data to the DB" is only triggered, when all 4 columns have a different value than they had before the edits. I would like to achieve this in frontend

Comment: I think you need to define a new layer class that inherits from QgsVectorLayer and overrides the relevant "save" or "write" method to only run when your constraint is fulfilled. Its probably too specialised a task to answer here, and of little use to anyone else, so try one of the QGIS consulting companies and get your credit card out.